# Can't access Chive/index.php on Fortrabbit

Tags: laravel, fortrabbit

When I open http://[my-app].eu1.frbit.net/chive. I get

```
       Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

Chive directory is on htdocs/chive and I removed from chive/.htaccess

```
       Options +FollowSymLinks
```

but still can't access.

Comment: I found the problem was the root folder was /public. I can access chive now but I get this error on login PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happened to me. Problem with your Chive login is that you didnt entered corectly fortrabbit credentials for mysql (not for your app). You should get those credentials by email, upon login to fortrabbit.

Take a look at this:[image: correct way to login, with mysql creds]